# error as "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSevlet " after adding Maven dependencies in project propert

Tags: java, spring, maven

Please help me to solve this issue and i am new to spring
i made a JSP Project with Tomcat 1.7 (maven project) but when I run the page, i get an `ClassNotFoundExcption`.

I have dao, controllers, service,model layer in my project.

### MY error

```
Jan 09, 2019 11:41:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [spring-mvc] in web application [/eFriends] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherSevlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jan 09, 2019 11:41:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 09, 2019 11:41:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 09, 2019 11:41:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1297 ms
```

Please find the pom.xml file below.I had adding maven plugin. And also I am new to spring and I don't know how to resolve this issue.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.eFriends.efriends</groupId>
<artifactId>eFriends</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>eFriends Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.9</mysql.connector.version>
     <maven-compiler-plugin-version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Servlet-Api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>eFriends</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Duplicated servlet api - but thats not the culprit

Comment: Instead of using plain spring boot dependecies, use starters - those have everything organized for you. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Don't use special blocks when asking your question. Simply write it, use special blocks for code or messages (logs, errors, etc.)

Comment: Check you `web.xml` file, you have a typo in `DispatcherSevlet`, it's DispatcherSe**r**vlet